# Custom enable/disable select rows MUI-DataTable

Tags: reactjs, customization, mui-datatable

I have a Mui-DataTable and I need to personalize the rows selection. In the documentation, I found the "isRowSelectable" function. But this method returns me only two parameters: dataIndex and selectedRows. In my table, I have a column called status, with two states: active and inactive. When the row status is inactive, I need to disable the row selection. Unfortunately, the "isRowSelectable" API doesn't return my data to compare the status and, so, enable or disable my row selection.

Does anyone have any idea of how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution". It's working, but it's not a beautiful way to solve the problem. Nevertheless, here is my approach:

- At first, my data came from a database. I change my get method sort in asc, setting my inactive columns at the final table;
- Secondly, I count how many rows and how many rows are inactive;
- Finally, in my "isRowSelectable", I return true if is my top table or false if is my bottom table based on my dataIndex, like below:

```
return dataIndex < totalRows-countStatus ? true : false
```

As I stated before, it isn't beautiful, but it's working well.